# Depedency Injection In ASP.net controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, dependencies, code-injection

I am working on a project with Entity Framework. I want to know is it normal to use Dependency Injection for Entity connection for unit testing. I want to start from little then dive into the world of DI, and also I use (have tested in a simple app) Autofac as container.
Also a question for future, If I have more than 50 viewmodels, how I suppose to use dependency injection for them. I have read in the net that it's not normal to have more than 5 dependencies in controller constructor.

Comment: dependency injection is not restricted just for unit testing, it is for loose coupling of modules

Comment: I am a starter, and starting without goal is not my style, for the start I want to know how to use DI for unit testing, especially for database, because the app I use has many insert forms.

Comment: have you googled how to use DI in asp.net mvc?

Comment: I have tested, and I can use it. I even found solutions, but I'm not competent enough yet to use them correctly, I need to learn more about DI. I want to fast start with database object injection, then during my spare time I'll read more about using DI efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question doesn't really belong on stackoverflow, I'll try and give you a nudge in the right direction by suggesting two really useful opensource frameworks.

- [`Ninject`](http://www.ninject.org/) is really easy to use and will make implementing dependency injection a lot more pleasant and structured.
- [`Moq`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) is used for writing unit tests and helps with "[mocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)", which is crucial to MVC and any kind of dependency injections.

Both frameworks are easy obtainable with the [`NuGet Package Manager`](https://www.nuget.org/).

There are plenty of tutorials and demos available all over the web, but [here](http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/24/dependency-injection-with-ninject-moq-and-unit-testing/) is a simple tutorial for writing unit tests using these two frameworks  to start you off.

Comment: I have read Pro MVC 5 book of Adam Freeman (he was using Ninject and Moq), but when reading I hadn't got computer. Autofac is like Ninject. I want to test my program without inserting information to the real database

Comment: Thats what moq is for, you don't need Ninject to use moq.

Comment: I didn't know that I can use Moq withoud Injection, yes, logically it is so, ok then my primary goal will be moq :D thanks